# YAWS: porting from 1.87 to 2.0.4

Tags: configuration, erlang, yaws

I decided to make an upgrade of a my system where run Erlang with a web interface based on YAWS. I have already recompiled the Erlang part, and testing the web part I have an error during the login handled by YAWS.

In particular, I'm using YAWS in embedded mode and the configuration is:

```
#sconf{listen       = Ip,
         servername   = HostName,
         port         = get_port(),
         docroot      = get_docroot(),
         errormod_404 = ?MODULE,
         partial_post_size = 1000000,
         authdirs = [#auth {dir = ["/"], realm = Realm, type="Basic", users = [{User, Pwd}]}]}
```

get_port() and get_docroot() are correct, the values come from the configuration file as the User and Pwd values.

When I connect to the web interface, the browser show me the login form, so I insert the right account but when I confirm what happens is:

```
Yaws process died: {function_clause,
                   [{yaws_server,'-handle_auth/4-fun-1-',
                        [{"admin","admin"}],
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2175}]},
                    {lists,any,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1225}]},
                    {yaws_server,handle_auth,4,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2178}]},
                    {yaws_server,is_auth,5,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2045}]},
                    {yaws_server,is_req_auth,3,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2032}]},
                    {yaws_server,handle_normal_request,5,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1932}]},
                    {yaws_server,aloop,4,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1242}]},
                    {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1065}]}]}
```

and the login fails.

I looked for the solution in the YAWS documentation but I found anything, it seems that my configuration is correct (it is the same that works without problems with the previous YAWS version).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Matteo

Answer (score 1):

The new version expects the users field to be a list of 4-tuples, not 2-tuples. (That's why the fun crashes in file "yaws_server.erl", line 2175.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, Richard.

I have read the code (yaws_server.erl) and also the Erlang documentation about the crypto:hash function, so finally I find the problem:

in my case, the correct configuration for the users list is

```
#sconf{listen       = Ip,
     servername   = HostName,
     port         = get_port(),
     docroot      = get_docroot(),
     errormod_404 = ?MODULE,
     partial_post_size = 1000000,
     authdirs = [#auth {dir = ["/"], realm = Realm, type="Basic", users = [{User, md4, Salt, crypto:hash(md4, [Salt,Pwd])}]}
```

In a second step, I will remove the clear text Pwd, with the hashed value.

Thanks a lot.